# Attempting to identify modify date of NTuser.dat and delete if 90 days old

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm new to PowerShell and trying to teach myself it so I can further my career. I've come up with a script to help my business (and impress my boss!) that basically gets a list of all the profiles on the machines from "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users" and I want it to identify if the NTUser.dat file is older than 90 days. If true, then delete that profile folder.

I've had a look around and attempted to write my own script using bits adapted from examples on here and the internet. As far as I can tell it works but it's not detecting how old the NTUser.dat is on the PC and the result is always the same. I'll paste it below. Please keep in mind my code may not be perfect :)

Any help or advise anyone can give would be much appreciated.

```
$excludeFolders = @("Administrator","sysmgmt","Default User","All Users")
$FolderPath = "C:\Documents and Settings"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$LastModified = $CurrentDate.AddDays(-90)

$Folders = Get-Childitem –path $FolderPath |
Where {$_.psIsContainer} |
Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastModified"} |
Where {$excludeFolders -notcontains $_.Name}

$NTuserFolderPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\$Folders.name\NTUser.dat"

If ($Folders) {
    foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {

            If ($NTuserFolderPath.LastWriteTime -gt $LastModified) {

                Write-Host "$($Folder.Name) needs removing"
            } Else 
            {
                Write-Host "Skipping $($Folder.Name)"
            }
    }
} Else {
    Write-Host "There are no files to empty."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues both coming from this line:

```
$NTuserFolderPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\$Folders.name\NTUser.dat"
```

1. The property `$Folders.name` wont expand properly in a quoted string without having it in a subexpression.
2. Since this line is not inside the loop the variable `$NTuserFolderPath` will *always* be the same.

So your loop should look like this instead

```
foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {

        $NTuserFolderPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\$($Folder.name)\NTUser.dat"
        If ((Get-Item $NTuserFolderPath).LastWriteTime -gt $LastModified) {
            Write-Host "$($Folder.Name) needs removing"
        } Else {
            Write-Host "Skipping $($Folder.Name)"
        }
}
```

You should also use `Test-Path` to check if the file exists first.

While I cant find a reference for it right now I would like to mention that checking the date of the ntuser.dat is not the most reliable way to see if a user account is stale on the local machine. Nothing could change in the registry but the user still be active. So just be careful and test.